# Is it against Java standards to name a class same as its package?

Tags: javabeans

If I have a package called xx.yy.product to group all product-related beans together, will it be against Java standards to have a bean called Product also within same package?

```
xx.yy.product 
      |
      |-> Product.java
      |-> ProductCategory.java
      |-> ProductAlert.java
       ...
```

Thanks, 
Paddy

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't break any Java standard.

In your example, which is correct, packages are written with lower case. So you have `com.xxx.product`

According to Java standard class should start with uppercase letter. In this case Product. So it is clear that `com.xxx.product` refer to package and `com.xxx.product.Product` refer to class.